# How to write a script in python that can open a new linux terminal and do source automatically

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-shell

I need to write a scirpt in python (or bash) which:

- open a new linux terminal with a few tabs
- do a 'source myfile.csh' command on each of the tab

I've tried with something like this:

```
 os.system("gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=/repo/ -e 'source myfile.csh' ")
```

but it didn't work (for example file was not found even though I was in a correct directory or can't open a .csh file blah blah blah)

I've also tried a few other options, but I didn't find a proper soultion for my problem.

I don't know why I can't do a simple "open a new terminal, write a command and execute it"

Maybe is there any simple solution WITHOUT installing any new software (I don't have a root)?

Comment: Any error message when doing the shown command?

Comment: does this command work when pasting in a terminal?

Comment: "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "source" (No such file or directory)" @languitar

Comment: Masquerading this as a Python question is extremely obscure.  If you can pull it off from the command line, you can then run it from Python (or Ruby, or C, or ...)

Comment: @tripleee You marked my question as duplicate but the topic proposed by you as an answer didn't solve my problem at all. I also removed the python tag

Comment: What is the precise problem you are trying to solve here?  Not realizing you have to run `tcsh` or `csh` in order for `source` to work seems like a good guess as to how to reduce the problem to a [MCVE](/help/mcve) and any remaining roblem seems like a tangential `csh`-only problem which should probably be a new question.  If you can clarify your question to rescope it to a simpler problem with a single straightforward answer, I'll be happy to lift the duplicate flag (though it seems somewhat likely that it will then be a duplicate of another existing question).

Comment: If your shell is `tcsh` then in no event is this a [tag:bash] question either, but I'm hesitant to remove the tag before we know what exactly would help you accomplish what you need.  The "error: must source" looks like an error from the script itself, but it's completely obscure why this is a requirement in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

`-e` will execute a process. However `source` is an instruction of your shell. What you need to do is to call your shell with `-e` and pass arguments to the shell in order to execute the `source` instruction. Should be something like

```
os.system("gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=/repo/ -e 'tcsh -c \"source myfile.csh\"'")
```

Comment: My terminal closes immediately after executing a srcipt. Is there any command to hold it up?  I need to work within it.

Comment: add `; sleep 1000` to the command passed to tcsh.

Comment: "Error: must source script, cannot just execute..."

Comment: And if you open a terminal manually and do `source myfile.csh`, it works???

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: So to be completely candid here, can you verify that you tried exactly the command `gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=/repo/ -e 'tcsh -c \"source myfile.csh; sleep 1000\"'` and it didn't work?

Comment: Exactly and if I open a terminal manually and type source myfile.csh it works perfectly.

Comment: Seems like python script is not setting the $_  value which brings myfile.csh to crash